# How do I get support library widgets to appear in Android Studio palette?

Tags: android, android-studio, drawerlayout

Running Android Studio 0.2.7 (latest version) with the v4-18 (latest version) of the support library. The visual editor won't allow me to edit layouts containing widgets from the support library. They don't appear in the palette, and I get a blank screen and a blank 'Rendering Error' message (no associated stack trace) when I try to load a file where I've included DrawerLayout by hand. The code builds and runs with the support library classes used just fine - it's only the editor that's causing me problems. Anyone experienced this problem?

For the record, it's not the issue with having to specify the height of the DrawerLayout explicitly - that should be fixed in v4-18, and I've tried specifying it just to be on the safe side with no results (I also don't get the exception that comes with that bug...)